# How to include newLine characters that BufferedReader ignores

Tags: java, sockets, cryptography, bufferedreader

I need to use buffer reader to communicate over sockets and I was just wondering as to how I could preserve the new lines. I wish to eventually use this in cryptography so I cant assume new lines are at the end of the message.

I am new to sockets in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The text the client side is sending

```
   ct.txt3nd0fh34d3rl1n31663nd0fh34d3rl1n3This is a test message to see if the file decrypts properly. Nothing special in this file.
   Just a pure test to see if my code works. Two chemists walk into a bar...
```

the length of the string is 205

in the server side i get

```
    ct.txt3nd0fh34d3rl1n31663nd0fh34d3rl1n3This is a test message to see if the file decrypts properly. Nothing special in this file.
    Just a pure test to see if my code works. Two chemists walk into a bar...
```

the length of this one is 206, it is adding 1 new line character at the end. This was after i tried implementing some solutions i found but they didnt work as I am off by 1 character.
Here is the code that reads the client input

```
while (incoming != null)
    {
        /* If the client has sent "exit", instruct the server to
         * remove this thread from the vector of active connections.
         * Then close the socket and exit.
         */
        if (incoming.compareTo("exit") == 0)
        {
            parent.kill (this);
            try {
                in.close ();
                sock.close ();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {/*nothing to do*/}
            return;
        }

        /* If the client has sent "die", instruct the server to
         * signal all threads to shutdown, then exit.
         */
        else if (incoming.compareTo("die") == 0)
        {
            parent.killall ();
            return;
        }   

        System.out.println("LINE: " + incoming.length() + " " + incoming);
        if(incoming.equals("3nd0f5krr4hf1l3") && !msgGotten)
        {
            //Decrypt
            SecretKeySpec key = CryptoUtilities.key_from_seed("H".getBytes());

            System.out.print(message);
            System.out.println(message.length());
            byte[] encryptedMessageAndDigest = message.getBytes();
            byte[] decryptedMessageAndDigest = CryptoUtilities.decrypt(encryptedMessageAndDigest, key);

            if(CryptoUtilities.verify_hash(decryptedMessageAndDigest, key))
            {
                byte[] headerMessage = CryptoUtilities.extract_message(decryptedMessageAndDigest);

                String payload = new String(headerMessage);

                String[] plainTextArray = payload.split("3nd0fh34d3rl1n3", 3);
                String fileName = plainTextArray[0];
                byte[] plaintextBytes = plainTextArray[2].getBytes();

                try 
                {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                    fos.write(plaintextBytes);
                    fos.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Otherwise, just echo what was received. */
            //System.out.println ("Client " + idnum + ": " + incoming);

            if(incoming.length() == 0)
            {
                message = message + "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                message = message + incoming + "\n";
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: at the end of my initial transmission, I send 3nd0f5krr4hf1l3 signify it. I would need `readLine()` so i can parse in one go, but if `read()` is truly the best way to go, how would i implement this? Would the \n (\r\n) charatcers come through in a read?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't assume there are line terminators, obviously you can't use `readLine()` in the first place. You should use one of the `read()` overloads.

> Would the `\n` (`\r\n`) charatcers come through in a read?

All characters will come through in a `read()`.

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that whenever a newline is in the original text, it becomes to separate tokens, but I cant seem to make it work when the token is = newline.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of that, but if you want to preserve the line terminators, don't use `readLine()`.